# Parsing elements to dict

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I am new to python programming and i am working on getting the ind_elements from the xml file to a dict.

I was able to parse the file and get the output. the output of the file trough the code are as follows:

The code is as follows:

```
for ind_list in reflist:
    for i in ind_list.attributes.keys():
        print(ind_list.attributes[i].name)
        print(ind_list.attributes[i].value)  




name
sankar
title
student
age
25
user_2
2012-05-08
user_3
2012-05-08

name
sankar
title
student
age
25
user_1
2012-05-08
user_2
2012-05-08

name
sankar
title
student
age
25
user_4
2012-05-08
user_5
2012-05-08
```

The issue right now are as follows:
1) I want to insert these elements into a dictionary. I want to insert it dynamically. 
2) As you can see from the output, each and every line of the xml file is different. How to add a key dynamically into the dict and not to add it, when it is already present?

I want these individual values to insert it into the database. I have worked with database coding from a dict before. So i can code that part.

Comment: most xml-parsing libraries offer this functionality out of the box. Check out xmltodict and lxml for starters.'

Comment: Please improve your question with a sample XML file, full current code relevant to parsing your XML and a sample dictionary to show how you want to organize your data for database import. That will illustrate your question much better!

Comment: Do not waste time creating dicts. Just iterate over xml and create database queries. Look at this approach and tell us why this is not working for you - http://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html#watching-events-while-parsing

Answer (score 1):

You should use [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) then, from xmltodict document;

```
>>> doc = xmltodict.parse("""
... <mydocument has="an attribute">
...   <and>
...     <many>elements</many>
...     <many>more elements</many>
...   </and>
...   <plus a="complex">
...     element as well
...   </plus>
... </mydocument>
... """)
>>>
>>> doc['mydocument']['@has']
u'an attribute'
>>> doc['mydocument']['and']['many']
[u'elements', u'more elements']
>>> doc['mydocument']['plus']['@a']
u'complex'
>>> doc['mydocument']['plus']['#text']
u'element as well'
```

Comment: Hi i have already tried using both the lxml and xmltodict concepts. If i use the concepts, it gets more complicated. Also the xml file i am parsing has several tags, sub-tags and so on. Each with a diff attribute.  AFter much research i have finally decided to use minidom, which is fairly simple. I am able to get the values i want using minidom, and after proceeding that i got the following output.

Comment: I want to use dict concept to actually create a perfect list that i can use for insertion.

Comment: No, not agree with you.I use xmltodict for my regular xml doc works and it simplifies to work with xml docs. After creating the docs, if you stuck sth. you can ask again.

Comment: I have to add something, the input file is of xml type but not an xml and i have a feeling that we are deviating from the problem i have now.

Comment: xml <-> dict operations, because of the dict's power, when i convert my data from xml to dict, it is easy to apply programming level operations such as sorting, searching, inserting etc.

Comment: One more thing is that, the structure of the file is not properly structured. it does not have a proper structure. and the file is of type .ana

Comment: and mainly for the problem i am working on ´, xmltodict is not a suitable option

Comment: I am not familiar with .ana file structure, i answered for "Parsing XML elements to dict". But,maybe, you can find .ana for xml converter and the use xmltodict,i am not sure if it exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do not waste time creating dicts. Just iterate over xml and create database queries.

This style of processing is more natural for some operations, such as converting XML input to some other format. This technique can be used to convert list of podcasts from the earlier examples from an XML file to a CSV file, so they can be loaded into a spreadsheet or database application.

Look at this approach and tell us why this is not working for you.

- [Parsing XML Documents](http://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html#watching-events-while-parsing)